# C/Objective-C read and get last digit of integer?

Tags: objective-c, c, integer, nsinteger, digit

How can i get the last digit of an integer (or NSInteger) outputted to integer?

example:

```
int time = CFAbsoluteGetCurrent();
int lastDigit;
```

Comment: Don't you just need to mod by 10 (time % 10)?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation):

```
int lastDigit = time % 10;
```

Comment: wow that worked!! i wasn't thinking in simple math terms. thanks!!

Comment: This is what I used many times when I started learning programming! Simple but yet helpful. Thanks =)